# Binding nested Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, listbox

I have a ListBox nested inside a ListBox.

XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Scenes}">

<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SceneNumber}"/>

   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EquipmentPerScene}"> 
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock>
                       <Run Text="{Binding Path=Item}"/>
                 </TextBlock>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
</ListBox>
```

I have two collections. One ‘Scenes’ holds all the scenes. And I have another collection which holds the Equipment. Now I want to pair the Equipment Collection with the Scenes so it displays the Equipment per scene. How do I do this?

Model

```
public class Scene 
{
    public Scene(string SceneNumber, string SlugLine)
}

public class Gear 
{
    public Equipment(string SceneNumber, string Item)
}
```

ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<Scene> Scenes { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Gear> AllEquipment { get; set; }
```

I tried this but this doesn’t seem to work. I don’t know the filterparameter.
Or is this the complete wrong approach?

```
private ListCollectionView _equipmentPerScene;
public ListCollectionView  EquipmentPerScene
{
    get
    {
        if (_equipmentPerScene == null) //important for loading the app
        {
            _equipmentPerScene = new ListCollectionView(AllEquipment);
            _equipmentPerScene.IsLiveFiltering = true;
            _equipmentPerScene.Filter = o =>
            {
                var gear = o as Gear;
                return gear!= null && gear.SceneNumber == ??????????;
            };
        }
        return _equipmentPerScene;
    }
    set
    {
        _equipmentPerScene = value; RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
 }
```

How can I pair that the EquipmentPerScene displays the right Equipment for that particular listboxItem (scene).

Comment: Why not to use grouping instead?

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you need a mechanism that can display an extended data about each Scene object. I can think about two approaches.

**Examples**
 1. The first is a master/details approach, each selected scene cause to refresh of the EquipmentPerScene collection view. For this approach you need to add the SelectedScene property, and when the selected scene is changed you will start the Update method which will refresh your collection view. This case will provide you with the SceneNumber for filtering (SelectedScene object will).
 2. The second is a Scene object extension approach, each Scene object will provide its own collection of equipment like you tried to do (your solution has bag with the ListBox tag nesting). For this approach you need to add the EquipmentPerScene observable collection property to Scene class and re-template the each ListBoxItem of Scenes Listbox. Like that:

```
       <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Scenes}">
       <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
               <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                   <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type soListBoxStyleHelp:Scene}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=SceneNumber}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding EquipmentPerScene}">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <TextBlock>
                                                    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Item}"/>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
           </Style>
       </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ListBox>
```

I'll glad to help if you will have problems with code and explanations.
Regards,